# Filesystem database vs. actual database

Tags: c#, sql, json, database, sqlite

I'm writing some relatively simple inventory software. The software just tracks stock counts for specific items along with item physical condition and any notes about the item. The database won't be growing very quickly, but in a few years time it could have maybe around ~1000 entries.

Right now I'm converting the item objects to JSON and storing them in the filesystem just in folders and text files. This is good because the objects can just be stored in Google Drive and accessed from other machines via their services. I can't host a remote database so this solution works well, but I'm worried about scaling. Once the entries become more numerous, would searches/queries become problematic with a filesystem database? I need this to be relatively snappy.

So again, for this type of software, would a local SQL database be better? With something like SQLite, am I able to somehow store the database in Google Drive so it can be accessed elsewhere without hosting it remotely?

This is my first application that needs a local database. Thanks for your patience!

I'm making it in C# Winforms.

Comment: [Developing a REST Web Service using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/112470/developing-a-rest-web-service-using-c-a-walkthroug)

Comment: On a scale of hundreds of records *per year* performance will not be an issue with any solution, at all.  However, if multiple instances of the application are going to be accessing the data simultaneously then your best bet by far is to use a hosted database somewhere.  Storing in files means you'd be managing concurrency yourself, and that's not a simple problem to solve.  Using a file-based database engine is fine, until you introduce things like cloud file sync tools.  Then you're right back to concurrency problems and race conditions.

Comment: @David hey thanks for the reply, at this time it will only be one surface tablet writing data at all, but the data should be able to be viewed from other machines so I suppose the easy route is just a filesystem.